# Images don't display but can see them using their URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, php, wordpress, file-permissions

So my website doesn't display the images for some reason but these images are being displayed alone on their single URLs. By the way I am using WordPress

Here is the screenshot of how it looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfNwv.png

However, the URL of these images work fine for example

http://phanime.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/korra-2.jpg

This url shows the image perfectly but in the actual screenshot the image is not displayed at all.

I think there is some issue  with the server maybe I don't have the permissions done correctly, although the uploads folder that includes all these images have the 777 permission so it should be fine.

Here is the url of the page that doesn't show any images: phanime.com

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault, Maaz! `all these images have the 777 permission` Please never set 777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In http://phanime.com/wp-content/themes/sahifa/style.css you are setting `img` elements to have `opacity: 0` so they are being shown completely transparent. Change that to 100, or remove it, and they show up.